# Plot.ly data streaming fails after random period of time

Tags: c#, networkstream, http-streaming

I've implemented simple rest client for Plot.ly Streaming API, which sends temperature measurements every 5 seconds. All works fine, but at some point process just stops and new dots are not appearing. This can happen withing 15 minutes after start or 1 hour. Tcp connection remains open, underlying stream remains writable, but new points just not showing on the graph. I figured out empirically that Content-Length header has impact on that - if it's large - all works fine for a loner period.

My client is written in C#. Basically i'm writing to opened NetworkStream raw Http request:

```
private static string GetStringRequest(string host, string token, string data)
{
        var sb = new StringBuilder()
            .AppendLine($"POST http://{host}/ HTTP/1.1")
            .AppendLine($"Host: {host}")
            .AppendLine("Connection: keep-alive")
            .AppendLine("Content-Type: application/json")
            .AppendLine("Content-Length: " + Int64.MaxValue)
            .AppendLine("Cache-Control: no-cache")
            .AppendLine($"plotly-streamtoken: {token}")
            .AppendLine("")
            .AppendLine("")
            .Append(data);

        return sb.ToString();
}

// this is called every 5 seconds
public void WriteMeasurement(float value, DateTime dateTimeUtc)
{
        var data = GetData(...);
        var request = GetStringRequest(Host, _token, data);

        _writer.Write(request); // network stream writer
}
```

Comment: How do you know that TCP connection is connected (not just open)?  The server could of closed connection due to inactivity.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see if connection is really working.

Comment: Well, I'm not certain about TCP connection. It's just my assumption. It shouldn't disconnect since [conditions for disconnection](https://plot.ly/streaming/) are not met. Using wireshark might help, thanx for advice :)

Comment: Typing from a cmd.exe window : netstat -a will give status of the connection.  The Http Request has a 'Status' property which would give one of the error messages in the link you provided.  A 200 Done would indicate the connection was closed by either the client or server, or router if you have more than one hop.  The call every 5 seconds may appear as a Service Attack by some servers and maybe causing the issue.  I wondering if you change the timer to every 30 seconds if you still drop the connection.